# Visual C++ holding the console open, strange behavior

Tags: c++, console

I've searched around here first, and seen many solutions to making Visual C++ hold the console open at the end of program's execution, but I'm getting some weird behavior from one of the methods, and I don't understand where this behavior is coming from.

So (a) what's the best method (besides crtl-F5 and setting subsystem to console) to hold the console open?

and (b) why am I getting the strange behavior that I will now elaborate on?

Here is the code

```
/* 

Learning how about variables and accepting inputs

*/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std; // cout and cin from the standard namespace. 
// using std::cout; -- alterative declarations
// using std::cin;

int main()
{
    char first, last; 

    cout << "Please enter your first and last names:\n";
    cin >> first; // get one char
    cin.ignore(256,' ');

    cin >> last; // get one char

    cout << "Your first and last initials are " << first << last;
    cin.ignore('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

The strange behavior is, I have to press the Enter exactly 4 times before it will exit the console.

Why 4 times?

Comment: Consider what value `'\n'` has (0x0a, i.e. 10), then consider what an invoke of [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) does when you pass that character literal rather than a count as the first parameter.

Comment: I might add as an extra exercise, try entering *just* your initials as your name and see how many strokes on the Enter key it takes to finally kill the program. It should be considerably more than four.

Comment: In Visual Studio, I've found the quickest and dirtiest way to accomplish what you're wanting is with a simple `system("pause");` call at the end of main.